# Django don't send email message with attached zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email, sendgrid

everyone! I have a problem with sending an email with Django smtp email backend and SendGrid. My view is below.
It makes batch of pdf files with pyppeteer, zip them to archive, attaches to the message and then send it to the email. It should be, but it doesn't work!
I checked it with other view for email sending(a little bit diff logic without zip or something.) and it worked but this means that it's not the problem with sendgrid and any other stuff like secret keys in uwsgi configuration.

The fact is, emails don't stuck in send grid list.
I tried to put some dummy bites instead of pdf file like `pdf_file = b'some bytes'` and it worked on my local machine but didn't work on server. I got the size of zip-archive from a response. Please explain to me where I'm wrong.

```py
### views.py
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def generate_batch_pdf(request, blueprint):
    try:
        payload = json.loads(request.body)

        email = payload.get('email')
        uuids = payload.get('uuids')

        zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'a', compression, False) as f:
            for uuid in uuids:
                report_name = _report_name(uuid, blueprint)
                pdf_file = async_to_sync(generate_pdf_file)(
                    request.get_host(),
                    uuid,
                    blueprint,
                    report_name,
                )
                f.writestr(
                    zinfo_or_arcname='{0}'.format(report_name),
                    data=pdf_file,
                )

        msg = EmailMessage(
            subject='Отчеты Тест',
            body='Архив выбранных отчетов',
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            to=[email],
        )

        msg.attach('reports.zip', zip_buffer.getvalue(), 'application/zip')
        msg.send(fail_silently=False)

        return JsonResponse(
            {
                'msg': 'Ok',
                # it's here just for check 
                'size': '{0}'.format(sys.getsizeof(zip_buffer)),
            },
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Err -> {e}'.format(e=e)})
```

I'm using `python 3.6`

```
### requirements.txt
django==3.1
...
```

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on where the error occurs. Can you explain what happens when you send the email with the zip file attachment? Does the `msg.send` method throw an error, and if so what is the error? You mentioned the SendGrid list, does the email make it to SendGrid but not get sent? What status is the email in the SendGrid dashboard. Please add error messages or screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @philnash, no error occurred. I would have seen it because I have try-except. I have `JsonResponse` with `Ok` message and size of zip file. More about SendGrid list. I don't see any message in list of sent messages. Then aren't getting stuck with error or something. I'm running Django with uwsgi and there is not errors in logs.

Comment: This sounds quite strange all round. You send the message, there are no errors yet it doesn't get sent or appear within SendGrid at all. Have you tried running this code without attaching the zip file to see if that works at all?